# How to replace port 25 with some other port on Webmin?

Tags: email

I am hosting a few websites on a VPS where my ISP asked me to disable port 25 to avoid spam. After doing that, I'm no more able to recieve or send emails using any of my domains' mail settings via 3rd party Email software. I changed the master config file of postfx to submission inet n – n – – smtpd and created new rule to allow port 465 in the linux firewall on webmin. When I tried using the following settings (previously working before port 25 was disabled), I can't access my mail, nor can I send. Am I missing anything? For example, I don't know where to replace (or assign) the incoming mail server's port 25 to port 465 in the webmin.

user@domain.com

username: user
password: abc

SMTP server:

mail.domain.com
port: 465

POP3 server:

mail.domain.com
port: 465

I have attached screenshots of the server settings as well.

http://tinypic.com/r/34pmas8/8 and 
http://tinypic.com/r/2ag6ems/8

Pls. advise. Thanks!!

Comment: Port 465 is normally used for secure SMTP connections. You will have to enable SSL or TLS in your mail settings. Are you running your own mail server?

Comment: Also port 25/465 are smtp (or outgoing) ports.  You can't set your POP3 to that too....  incoming and outgoing are always different ports.

Comment: yes, David, I'm running webmin with postfx.

Comment: Thanks Tyson. I'm trying to figure exactly that i.e. how to assign two different ports for incoming and outgoing in the mail server (postfx) of webmin?